# mysql select records in last hour, without date

Tags: mysql, datetime, comparison

I have a table of daily emails to be sent. So I'm storing a time of day, as a time field (00:00:00, without a date). A couple example rows might be:

```
mike, timeOfDay = 07:03 meaning "send mike an email daily at 7:03AM"
corey, timeOfDay = 23:30 meaning "send corey an email daily at 11:30PM"
```

At any given time, I want to find the emails to send from the last hour. For example, if I run this at 7:55AM, it should get all records between 6:55AM and 7:55AM. That will include mike's email. If the script runs at 12:15AM (00:15), it should get all records between 11:15PM (23:15) and 12:15AM (00:15). This will include corey's email.

I've looked at [every](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276110/mysql-select-records-1-hour-or-younger-on-datetime-column) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999416/find-records-produced-in-the-last-hour) on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999416/find-records-produced-in-the-last-hour) and the web, and they all seem to require a date in addition to the hour.

As close as I could come:

```
SELECT
  `notification`. *,
  now() as now,
  DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) as 1hourAgo
FROM `notification`
WHERE (
  `notification`.`timeofday` > DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR )
)
AND (
  `notification`.`timeofday` < NOW( )
)
```

I figured out a hack to match the hours of this hour and last, before now, but it seems, well, hackish. There must be a correct way to do this!

Here's the hack I've got.

```
SELECT
  `notification`. * ,
  HOUR( NOW( ) ) AS HOUR ,
  HOUR( DATE_SUB( NOW( ) ,
  INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) ) AS 1hourago,
  time( now( ) ) AS now
FROM `notification`
WHERE (
     HOUR( `notification`.`timeofday` ) = HOUR( NOW( ) )
  OR HOUR( `notification`.`timeofday` ) = HOUR( DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) )
)
AND (
  `notification`.`timeofday` < TIME( NOW( ) )
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you saved your `timeofday` field as a `TIME`, you can use this:

```
SELECT
  `notification`.*,
  TIME(NOW()) AS right_now,
  TIME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) AS one_hour_ago
FROM `notification`
WHERE (
  HOUR(NOW()) != 0
  AND `notification`.`timeofday` BETWEEN TIME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) AND TIME(NOW())
) OR (
  HOUR(NOW()) = 0
  AND (
       `notification`.`timeofday` BETWEEN TIME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) AND '24:00'
    OR `notification`.`timeofday` BETWEEN '0:00' AND TIME(NOW())
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks! My challenge is how to run this kind of query without providing the times. I don't want to have to figure out the logic that if the time is more than 24:00 I have to include an OR.

Comment: @Corey I've updated my answer with a more advanced query which should do what you're asking.

Comment: @Corey: Another update. This time it's tailored at your db, so if I'm not mistaken, you can use my current query "as is".

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what datatype your timeofday field is stored in.  I will assume it's a `TIME` field.

When you say "from the last hour" presumably you mean "times from the top of the previous hour until just before the top of the hour that just finished."  That is, for example, if you run this at 10:03, you want times in the range 9:00 inclusive to 10:00 exclusive.

Here's what you do.

```
SELECT TIME(TIME_FORMAT(n.timeofday,'%H:00:00')) as hour, n.whatever, n.whatelse
  FROM `notification` as n
 WHERE n.timeofday >= TIME(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR, '%H:00:00'))
   AND n.timeofday <  TIME(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:00:00'))
```

This will work with good performance even if you have a lot of rows in your notification table, if you put an index on the timeofday table.

If you are going into production any dependency on the present moment is a bad idea: various kinds of batch jobs, events, and cronjobs don't really, ever, run at exactly the moment you tell them to. If you follow the strategy of depending on the present moment as you run an hourly job, you'll occasionally send extra messages or miss some.  That's why you should consider using `TIME(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H:00:00'))` to truncate your present time to the current hour. It also copes with the midnight rollover just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I added that it's in fact a time field, and a couple examples about when it might run.